# using tweepy to post email to twitter

Tags: python, twitter, gmail, tweepy

I have built a script to read my Gmail inbox for a new email, if found store it for posting and mark the email as "read". Everything has been working fine there.

I have since been trying to fuse Tweepy into this to post said stored email to twitter. Except it looks like tweepy doesn't like my variable "part.get_payload()"

```
api.update_status("Test")
```

....works fine and posts to twitter

```
TweetMsg = part.get_payload()
api.update_status(TweetMsg)
```

....doesnt post anything to twitter

Looking through Tweepy documentation I couldnt find any info on using variables with Status Updates. Any Advice?

Comment: can you try printing the value of TweetMsg to the console? Does it contain any string data suitable for passing to update_status()?

Comment: Yes it prints to console with a simple Print() command. But I cant seem to get the variable to pass through tweepy api.

Comment: Is the value of TweetMsg a plain string? If you're using the Gmail Python API, it looks to me like get_payload() returns a nested object.